# How to find the coordinates of point Intersection between line and parabola in java

Tags: java, line, point, intersection

I am looking for an algorithm to find coordinates of point intersection between line and parabola in java programming if i know coordinates of 4 point  A,B,P1,P2,P3, who can help me, thanks very much

this is image (demo for my question) hope you help me, please

[image]

Comment: Where is the image? Does A and B two points of the line and P1, P2, P3 three points on the parabola?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with some math to turn 3 points into a parabola:

A<sub>1</sub> = -x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> +x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>

B<sub>1</sub> = -x<sub>1</sub> +x<sub>2</sub>

D<sub>1</sub> = -y<sub>1</sub> +y<sub>2</sub>

A<sub>2</sub> = -x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> +x<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup>

B<sub>2</sub> = -x<sub>2</sub> +x<sub>3</sub>

D<sub>2</sub> = -y<sub>2</sub> +y<sub>3</sub>

B<sub>m</sub> = -(B<sub>2</sub> / B<sub>1</sub>)

A<sub>3</sub> = B<sub>m</sub> * A<sub>1</sub> + A<sub>2</sub>

D<sub>3</sub> = B<sub>m</sub> * D<sub>1</sub> + D<sub>2</sub>

a<sub>p</sub> = D<sub>3</sub> / A<sub>3</sub>

b<sub>p</sub> = D<sub>1</sub> - A<sub>1</sub> * a<sub>p</sub>

c<sub>p</sub> = y<sub>1</sub> - a<sub>p</sub>x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> - b<sub>p</sub>x<sub>1</sub>

Parabola:

y = a<sub>p</sub>x<sup>2</sup> + b<sub>p</sub>x + c<sub>p</sub>

---

Turn 2 points into a line:

m<sub>L</sub> = (y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>) / (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>)

b<sub>L</sub> = y<sub>1</sub> - m<sub>L</sub>x<sub>1</sub>

Line:

y = m<sub>L</sub>x + b<sub>L</sub>

---

Intersections:

y = y

a<sub>p</sub>x<sup>2</sup> + b<sub>p</sub>x + c<sub>p</sub> = m<sub>L</sub>x + b<sub>L</sub>

a<sub>p</sub>x<sup>2</sup> + b<sub>p</sub>x + c<sub>p</sub> - m<sub>L</sub>x - b<sub>L</sub> = 0

a<sub>p</sub>x<sup>2</sup> + b<sub>p</sub>x - m<sub>L</sub>x + c<sub>p</sub> - b<sub>L</sub> = 0

a<sub>p</sub>x<sup>2</sup> + (b<sub>p</sub> - m<sub>L</sub>)x + c<sub>p</sub> - b<sub>L</sub> = 0

Either 0, 1, or 2 x values:

x = (-(b<sub>p</sub> - m<sub>L</sub>) ±√((b<sub>p</sub> - m<sub>L</sub>)<sup>2</sup> - 4a<sub>p</sub>(c<sub>p</sub> - b<sub>L</sub>)) ) / 2a<sub>p</sub>

Plug back into:

y = m<sub>L</sub>x + b<sub>L</sub>

for y values.

---